# How to get JSON as string data from HttpResponse in Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using Akka HTTP and want to get the JSON response from a Rest API.

```
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = uri, headers = List(authorization)))

responseFuture
  .onComplete {
    case Success(res) => {
      val strictEntity: Future[HttpEntity.Strict] = res.entity.toStrict(3.seconds)
      strictEntity.onComplete {
        case Success(se) => {
          se...
        }
        case Failure(sf) => {
          println(sf.getMessage)
        }
      }
    }
    case Failure(f) => {
      println("Error:  "+ f.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

I end up nesting a lot of those `onComplete` callbacks. Is this even the easiest way? What should I do to the `se` object to get the JSON as a string?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
val result: Future[String] = responseFuture.flatMap {
  case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, e, _) =>
    Unmarshal(e).to[String]
  case HttpResponse(status, _, e, _) =>
    e.discardBytes() //all entities should be consumed or discarded, so... 
    Future.failed(new InvalidHttpStatus(s"service returned ${status.intValue()}"))
}
```

Comment: ok, so the Unmarshal also creates a "strict" object? I was confused with what exactly happened there. Thanks.

Comment: the mainly idea of Unmarshal is to convert some low-level representation into a higher level object. In this example, it will consume  the response entity underneath and convert it into a String.